# Json incomprehensible length increase

Tags: java, json, gson

It's may be a dumb question but i don't know why the searilization of an object to json increase the size factor by at least 4.

for exemple I have a byte array with these carateristics

```
54351 length before serialization
198464 length after serialization
```

Edit:
code

```
byte b[] = Files.readAllBytes(imgFile.toPath());
System.out.println("size pic " +b.length);
String json = gson.toJson(b);
System.out.println("size pic json " +json.length());
```

Comment: And how are we supposed to help you without any code ? Whenever you ask a question ask yourself if you could answer it with a few more years of experience given the context you provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's take an example: the array `new byte[] {123, -77}`. This is an array of 2 bytes. It thus takes 2 bytes in memory. Transforming it to JSON produces the following string: `"[123,-77]"`. That makes 9 characters: `[`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `,`, etc. The 4-times factor thus looks pretty normal to me.

Comment: 2 bytes ? For an array of integers ? I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding your statement but that may show it isn't clear enough

Comment: It's not an array of ints, but an array of bytes. I clarified it anyway.